# Simple Java program runs in NetBeans IDE but not when built

Tags: java, netbeans

Good Afternoon Stackoverflow users.

I have created a simple java program that reads a file, stores each line and then allow the user to edit a certain part of the line and saves the file in another place.

This all works fine in the NetBeans IDE 11.2. I can run the project and it runs as expected and allows me to edit the files etc.

When I go to Clean and Build the project it creates the folders and gives me a .jar file along with other source files.

When I try to run the .jar file (windows 10 pro) outside the IDE it just flashes the CMD screen and then closes instantly. So I'm not sure if the issue is with my system and the JRE or, the program itself?

I am running a freshly installed JRE8 and NetBeans is linked to JDK13.

I have tried to create a bat file to run and I get the same result instant closure of the program.

I have included the simple program below:

```
package PaymentReferenceEditor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

public class Main 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader reading = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Z:\\BGCDATA.in"));
            int lines = 0;
            while (reading.readLine() != null) lines++;
            reading.close();
            
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("Z:\\BGCDATA.in");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\bacs\\BGCDATA.out");
            
            int l = 1;
            String c1;
            String c2;
            String c3;
            String c4;
            String c5;
            String line;
            String es;
            int el = lines -4;
            int cn;
            int tc;
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                if(l > 0 && l < 5)
                {
                    myWriter.write(line + "\n");
                }
                if(l > 4 && l < el)
                {
                    c1 = line.substring(0,46);
                    c2 = line.substring(46,64);
                    c3 = line.substring(64,82);
                    c4 = line.substring(82,100);
                    
                    cn = l - 4;
                    tc = el - 5;
                    
                    c5 = c4 + '\n' + c1 + ' ' + c2 + '\n';
                    
                    System.out.print(cn);
                    System.out.print(" of ");
                    System.out.println(tc);
                    System.out.println(c5);

                    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    frame,
                    cn + " of " + tc +"\n"
                    + c5,
                    "FloPlast Limited",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
                    
                    if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0) && (s.length() < 15)) 
                    {
                        showMessageDialog(null, c5 + " " + s );
                        //write line to file
                        es = String.format("%-18s",s);
                        es = es.toUpperCase();
                        myWriter.write(c1 + c2 + es + c4 +  "\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showMessageDialog(null, c5 + " " + c3 );
                        //write line to file
                        myWriter.write(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + "\n");
                    }
                    
                    //showMessageDialog(null, c5);
                }
                if(l > el)
                {
                    myWriter.write(line + "\n");
                }
                l++;
            }
            reader.close();
            myWriter.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }   
}
```

This problem really has left me scratching my head. I have checked file association and the JAR is linked to the java file.

Any help would be appricated.

Comment: How did you write exactly? Did you double-click on the jar file? Or did you run it from the command line? If the former could you try running it from the command line and sharing the error message you get?

Comment: Hi Don, I doubled clicked the JAR file and run it using a .bat file. I will run it using cmd line directly aswell, and update with results.  Ahh ok I get an error: and a clue: no main manifest attribute,

Comment: How are you running this in NetBeans?  I think you need to set a "main class" in NetBeans to get it to set that attribute when it builds your Jar file.  Check the project properties.

Comment: Hi Markspace, I select Run Project in NetBeans to test it. I have done a little research based on the above results and I need to edit the manifest, so I'm looking into that at the moment.

Comment: If you can "Run Project" then it should work on the command line too.  I think you may have found a bug in NetBeans.  Double check your project set up, but maybe head over to the NetBeans mailing list for some advice.